# printing variables values in python. Is there any elegant formatting to do it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

I would like to print variables values in python.
e.g:

```
a=3
b=5
print 'blah blah: a = {a}, b = {b}'.format(a=a, b=b)
```

result is:

```
blah blah: a = 3, b = 5
```

My question is how to do it in a short elegant and readable manner.

e.g., is there a way to write something like (pseudo code below)

```
print 'blah blah: {a}, {b}'.format(a,b)
```

to get the same result?

Thanks!
(BTW: i am using python 2.7)

EDIT (clarification):
For logging purpose, sometimes i have many variables that i would like to print, so i prefer not doing something like

```
print 'a={}, b={}, c={},...'.format(a,b,c...)
```

because it is a source for bugs (i.e. I just want to specify the varaible name in the string itself and not care about the order  of the variables).

e.g., ultimatly, something that looks like

```
print 'blah blah: {a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}'.format(c,e,a,f,d,b)
```

with a result like:

```
blah blah: a=3, b=5, c=7, d=22, e=2, f=532
```

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you have to repeat `a` and `b` in `a=a, b=b`?

Comment: yes, i find it not elegant to repeat the name of the argument 4 times in order to print its value.

Comment: The problem is that the objects themselves don't know what name[s] they are bound to.  If you want something like that you have to use a namespace (i.e. dict).

Comment: This reminds me of the MacroPy library, whose [`log`](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tracing) function seems to do what you want. `log[a]` prints out "a -> 3" (or something similar, I haven't actually tried it myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your second approach with `**locals()` instead of `a, b`. `locals()` returns a dict containing all local variables. `**` unpacks it so you can use it in function calls (`function(**{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 14})` is the same as `function(a=3, b=4, c=14)`)

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> c = 14
>>> print 'a = {a}, b = {b}'.format(**locals())
a = 3, b = 4
```

To avoid `'a = {a}'` you can do something like

```
print '{a}, {b}'.format(**{k:'{} = {}'.format(k,v) for (k,v) in locals().iteritems()})
```

Comment: Almost perfect!
Anyway to shorten it to get the same result?
e.g. something like
    print('{a}, {b}'.format(SOME_MANIPULATION(**locals())))

Comment: Not without creating a function which does this four you (converting `'{a}'` to `'a = {a}'`).

Comment: Thanks, I accept your answer, and will add my solution as an edit

Answer (score 1):

If you know the order that `a` and `b` will be in, you don't need to pass them as named arguments in your formatting:

```
a = 3
b = 5

print('blah blah: a = {}, b = {}'.format(a, b))
```

Alternatively you could store your variables in a dictionary as below and then use [`**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769475/3005188) unpacking when passing the dict to format.

```
d = dict(a=3, b=5)

print('blah blah: a = {a}, b = {a}'.format(**d))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. yet it is not what i was looking for. see my clarification in the question

Comment: I further clarified my question.

Comment: He wants the variable name and value to be printed out by putting the value in.

Answer (score 0):

```
import inspect

class fdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, dct):
        for k, v in dct.items():
            self[k] = "{} = {}".format(k, v)

def flocals():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    return fdict(frame.f_back.f_locals)

def localformat(string):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    dct = fdict(frame.f_back.f_locals)
    return string.format(**dct)
```

Then import `localformat` anywhere you want and use this:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 6
print(localformat('{a}, {b}'))
```

or call the `flocals()` to get a string to pass to format.